# automating conversion at both type and value level

Tags: typescript

so I have types and values like so (this is of course a simplified case)

```
type a = {
  f1: string;
  f2: string;
  f3: number;
  f4: number;
};
```

I want to be able to define a function like so:

```
function convertFieldsToBigInt<???, ???>(obj: ???, fields: ???): ??? { ??? }
```

such that it can be used as follows:

```
const b = convertFieldsToBigInt(obj, ['f1', 'f3]);
```

the type of b would be

```
type b = {
  f1: BigInt;
  f2: string;
  f3: BigInt;
  f4: number;
};
```

and the implementation would apply `BigInt()` to the given fees.

I'm still relatively new to typescript, especially this sort of programming in typescript, and am not quite sure how to do this at the type or the value level...well, I hack something together in one or the other, but have absolutely not clue how to do it in both.

The above would be more than enough, but the extra credit question would be how to push it one more step to something like:

```
function convertFields<???, ???>(obj: ???, fields: ???, function: A=>B): ??? { ??? }
```

where then the types would depend on the type of the function...eg it would expect an object with fields of type A, and return one with those fields now of type B, such that the above function would become

```
function convertFieldsToBigInt<???, ???>(obj: ???, fields: ???): ??? { return convertFields(obj, fields, BigInt); }
```

hope this makes sense and is a well-formed question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need in order to [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the properties of type `A` correctly is a check whether a key in type `A` `extends` a key in the array passed to the `convertFieldsToBigInt` function.

If yes -> set value type to `BigInt`. 
If no -> keep the value type of `A`.

In TypeScript one calls this a [Conditial Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

```
type A = {
  f1: string;
  f2: string;
  f3: number;
  f4: number;
};

const obj: A = {
  f1: "123",
  f2: "hello",
  f3: 456,
  f4: 789,
};

type FieldsToBigInt<T, U extends keyof T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends U ? BigInt : T[K];
};

function convertFieldsToBigInt<T, U extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  fields: U[]
): FieldsToBigInt<T, U> {
  // implementation
  return null as any;
}

const b = convertFieldsToBigInt(obj, ['f1', 'f3']);
// b {
//   f1: BigInt;
//   f2: string;
//   f3: BigInt;
//   f4: number;
// }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKAzAjALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbnUywCYDjzq6NsBmAigVwC2AIwgkODACy9BIsegC%20HdAGMA9hWJRVQgFYE4iVJ1wEARDkZdTAGnrZmUUwAsIAG1eqbdrDygSArABstsZSUADsABwAnCGK6OigkFAAYmRuACaEACqqAEJkVACSFMAAPNnWUACqUBAAHsAQFFlQANYQIKpYUNkAfAjIdgDaANJQlO2d3b0AugTjDU0thDVQAPxQBcWlUATZY7Mc8WjoWHwUysBk6lBqFABuosBpmTn5hSXllWtLza0dLo9foACjs2j0vRCDHSriyBGqw1m6AAlARXnD3tsvhUqtUBkZMAB6IkTARgVwQATNYAAQ2u6jsJAgwD4JAoUH47igtNWtIoIGOCTQ900QkG9yeJBesKyuWxpRBEKqwwA5LhVVV1VxVbMURwSVBxUZDQx8FtPqUDaSGA5WJRaOhTdwCArgNbMNgwvxhKIPfIgA)

P.S. You usually want to define type names starting with a capital.

Comment: thank you very much! going to put this into practice tomorrow! thank you so much

Comment: accepted :) an addon that I suppose could be it's own question, but do you know if it's possible to extend the above to respect `| null` `| undefined`? if it's not trivial I will post another question, thank you again

Comment: What exactly would you like to extend?

Comment: the logic of `FieldsToBigInt` such that if you have `type a = { f1: string | null; f2: string }` it is smart enough to return `type a = { f1: BigInt | null; f2: BigInt }`